# Spinner with Icon and Text like Phone App on Android (with Bluetooth)

Tags: android, bluetooth, spinner, android-alertdialog

I want to re-create the following:

[image]

Specifically, note the Bluetooth icon, clicking on it brings up what looks like a spinner? Or is it a dialog somehow located correctly? I couldn't find the phone app code anywhere, and am at a loss for how to best implement this.

Comment: This is the spinner you can achieve the same using appcompat

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured out the solution shortly after posting the question.

The correct solution is to use a [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html). Here is pretty much all you need to do:

```
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater
            = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext()
            .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.bluetooth_popup, null);

    popupView.findViewById(R.id.bluetooth).setOnClickListener(this);
    popupView.findViewById(R.id.speakerphone).setOnClickListener(this);
    popupView.findViewById(R.id.earpiece).setOnClickListener(this);

    popupWindow = new PopupWindow(
            popupView,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    // Together these two allow for the popupWindow to be dismissed when touch occurs outside
    popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
    popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
```

and then to show it anchored to a view:

```
popupWindow.showAsDropDown(speaker, 0, (int) (-160));
```

Hope this helps you out.